# Drupal 7 Display a list of reference node in node being display

Tags: nodes

I am new to Drupal 7.

I have two content types, they are 'school' and 'course'. In course content type, I used [Reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) to create a field that reference to school (a school have many courses, and a course is belong to one school only).

And now what I want is, when I view a specific school info, the list of courses that belong to the school also be displayed beneath.

How can I do that in drupal 7 ? :D
Thank you in advance!

Comment: With [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) you could simply use Views. Can't you do it with Reference?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a view of contents filter by `Course` content type. Now I assume you have a field name `field_school`.

Add this field in `Contextual Filter` and select default argument `Content ID from URL`.

When this block will be added on node page, it will automatically filters the `courses` of that school. Otherwise pass the school id as argument to view. :)

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sumit madan, Thanks you! I'm now can get a list of course by passing the school id as argument to view (in my case, it is: http://localhost/mtclanguage/?q=couse-list-of-school/1).
I don't know how to add the block to school node page?? Can you explain further how to do that?? :D

Comment: Yes, Just add a view display "block", in your block list you can see the block. You can assign that block any region. If you are using panel, then it will be available in panels too. For more detail you can google it. :)

Comment: Love to hear that. :)

Comment: @user48552 as soon as you're able, be sure to 'accept' this answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer body